# Why will a Fourier transform of a pickup placed at the middle of a string only result in odd harmonics?

Tags: string-theory, computational-physics

My physics teacher explained a lot of information about strings but he never went in depth with my question. What happens to the even harmonics and why are the odd ones the only ones picked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [guitar pickup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickup_(music_technology)) generally produces an electrical signal representative of the motion of the string.

Below is a diagram showing the motion of a string for the first several harmonics:
[image]

As you can see, the even-numbered harmonics have a [node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(physics)) (a point where the string doesn't move at all) at the midway point, and the odd harmonics don't.

When you pluck a guitar string, many of these harmonics are excited simultaneously, and the guitar string takes a shape and motion that is a superposition of all of the excited harmonics (with varying amplitudes). However, if you place a pickup at the midway point, the even numbered harmonics won't contribute anything to the electrical signal, since those harmonics don't contribute any motion at the midpoint.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it could go a bit further. You could explain that a generic motion of the string near the pickup contains parts from all harmonics. However, since the string's mode profile has no motion at the pickup for odd harmonics, the sound measured by the pickup essentially rejects any components at those odd harmonics.

Comment: @DanielSank That's a nice addition. Does that change capture what you had in mind?

Comment: Beautiful. Nice answer. I would point out though, that guitar pickups usually aren't in the middle of the string, so I don't know if the author's premise is even really correct.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it was just a hypothetical situation.